# "Couldn't find any resources appropriate for the specified culture...." - How to solve?

Tags: c#, resources, resx, culture

I am running a script in the a program to set a data environment.  It works fine, but if I try to add a new text box, or background image... I guess anything additional, it gives the following message: "[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMzt2.png)".  The script is in a seperate testing area and a '.resx' reference file is generated.  I tried to move the files into the default script folder for the program, along with '.resx' file, but it made no difference.

I am pretty new to writing code with C# and perhaps this is something simple I don't understand yet.  In addition to any solution offered, I am also appreciate of any concepts, analogies, philosophies associated with this problem, so I have a better fundamental understanding of this issue and potentially other issues and processes with Visual Studio; writing C#.

*There is a also a screenshot of the design mode, showing the dialog box.  The bottom part of the screenshot shows the added text box, but when this is added, the error message comes.  If I delete it, it usually works again, but sometimes not (another question could be, "What is a general function in Visual Studio to clear out references, etc. that are not being used after object(the added text box for example) are deleted).  Any help is appreciated.[Actual error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHxqc.png)[The script in design mode with added text box at bottom which causes error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Alx54.png)

I tried moving files in case the program utilizing the script "preferred" a particular file location.  I tried creating a visual studio project in the default program folder, in case the script needed to be in the project environment to function properly with '.resx' reference file and / or other files, objects or data that may be relevant.

I was expecting to make simple changes to dialog box and have it output.